# testing if button is disabled

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I have a simple form with 2 input boxes and a submit button.

```
<div class="login jumbotron center-block">
  <h1>Login</h1>

  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
      <div *ngIf="formErrors.username" class="alert alert-danger"> {{ formErrors.username }}  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <div *ngIf="formErrors.password" class="alert alert-danger"> {{ formErrors.password }}  </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" >Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now when the 2 input boxes are empty , the submit button should be disabled.
Visually it all works as expected, but I'd like to cover this in my unit testing as well.

The below  is shortened example as how I tried checking whether the button element is disabled or not. However it seems the `page.submitBtnEl.disabled` attribute is always true for some reason.

```
let InvalidUser = new User({
  username: '',
  password: ''
});

it('form validity should be False when entering invalid credentials', 
fakeAsync(() => {
    updateForm( InvalidUser );
    expect( page.submitBtnEl.disabled ).toBeTruthy("submit button is disabled");
    expect(comp.loginForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
  }));
```

Comment: Have you try triggering one round of change detection manually with `fixture.detectChanges()` (before your test)? Are you sure you have the correct value in `submitBtnEl`?

Comment: you're right I forgot to call the `fixture.detectChanges()` after updating the form.

Answer (score 1):

Add `fixture.detectChanges()` call before querying for your element and making the assertions.

```
it('should  be disabled when comment is empty', () => {
  updateForm( InvalidUser );

  fixture.detectChanges() // <-- add this to update the view

  submitBtn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button.btn-default'));

  // this asserts that button matches <button disabled>Hello</button>    
  expect(submitBtn.nativeElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual('');

  // this asserts that button matches <button>Hello</button>          
  expect(submitBtn.nativeElement.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual(null);
});
```

[image]

Happy Coding!